# Font size of JDialog title

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jdialog

How do I set the font size of the title of a JDialog.  I'm displaying JDialogs on extremely high resolution monitors (5 mega pixels), and the dialog titles are not legible.  I need to do this on a per dialog basis because the application is multi-monitor, and some dialogs appear on lower resolution monitors, and some on higher resolution monitors.

Comment: Isn't this more dependent on the OS than on Java/Swing?

Comment: yes, correctly, you are right, @Jon are you tried determine what GraphicEnviroment[] returns, sure depends of number of Monitors, nomber of GPU's and cores inside GPU (profesional GPU for 3D, program for architects ...), yes if you set L&F for concrete Native OS then you can change that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()`, but the title bar is not going to look native or like other normal dialogs, but you can try this.

```
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Test");
    dialog.getLayeredPane().getComponent(1).setFont(new Font("Lucida",Font.PLAIN,48));  
    dialog.setSize(300,100);  
    dialog.setLocation(400,200);  
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

outputs the following

[image]

Note: the `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()` method

> Provides a hint as to whether or not
>   newly created JFrames should have
>   their Window decorations (such as
>   borders, widgets to close the window,
>   title...) provided by the current look
>   and feel.

so there is no guarantee that it will work the same way on different settings, I would assume.

Comment: Thanks, this will do what I need it to do.

Comment: Dude, it doesn't work with Substance library, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to change the font size.  I would suggest creating a custom dialog based on a `Window` that would have a larger title and a close button.